# Concatenating string content VALUES of multiple arraylists . Strange problem

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I have many `Arraylists` having `String` objects , and I have a requirement to concatenate there values.
Eg:

```
ArrayList finalList = new ArrayList();
ArrayList catMe = new ArrayList();
ArrayList x = new ArrayList();
x.add("Green");
x.add("Red");
ArrayList y = new ArrayList();
y.add(" Apple");

//......

catMe.add(x);
catMe.add(y);

concatContents(catMe);  // Here i need to do 
                        // some concatenation magic.
```

so when `finalList` is printed:

```
finalList.get(0) // should show > "Green Apple"
finalList.get(1) // should show >  "Red Apple"
```

I know it looks easy if there are only two list X and Y... but I need it for n    dimensions. Say if there is 3rd list

```
ArrayList z= new ArrayList();
z.add(" USA");
z.add(" Canada");
catMe.add(z);
concatContents(catMe);
```

Now finalList should show

```
Green Apple USA
Green Apple Canada
Red Apple USA
Red Apple Canada
```

Do i need recursion? Unable to think how to implement though! Do any java master there have a solution?

Comment: Recursion would certainly provide a simple method to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive answer.  Just cooked it up, so no guarantees on quality... :)

```
public ArrayList<String> concatLists(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list) {
    ArrayList<String> catStrs = new ArrayList<String>();
    int len = list.size();
    if (len == 1) {
        catStrs.addAll(list.get(0));
        return catStrs;
    }
    ArrayList<String> myStrs = list.get(0);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> strs = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    strs.addAll(list.subList(1, len));
    ArrayList<String> retStrs = concatLists(strs);
    for (String str : myStrs) {
        for (String retStr : retStrs) {
            catStrs.add(str+retStr);
        }
    }
    return catStrs;
}
```

Comment: I was going to post a recursive version, but you beat me to it!  That said, there's a number of possible improvements here.

Comment: You're welcome!  This actually is a recursive solution, if that was your question. Recursion is a method calling itself. So `ArrayList<String> retStrs = concatLists(strs); ` makes this recursive.

Comment: @BenCole U r right!  I noticed that after posting comment. Please Ignore.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work. (I did not actually compile this, wrote it as sorta pseudo code for simplicity. take care of generics and proper types list List>)

```
List<ArrayList> lists;  // add all your lists to this list
ArrayList<String> final_list; // your final list of concatenations

for (int i=0; i<list1.size(); i++) {
    String temp = ""
    for (ArrayList current_list : lists) {
       temp += " " +current_list.get(i);
    }
    final_list.add(temp);
}
```

EDIT -- okay so the code above was bit stupid, i had not understood the question correctly. Now as others have posted the recursive solutions, I thought would pay off by posting a non recursive working solution. So here is the one that works exactly as expected

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
    x.add("Green");
    x.add("Red");
    ArrayList<String> y = new ArrayList<String>();
    y.add(" Apple");
    ArrayList<String> z = new ArrayList<String>();
    z.add(" USA");
    z.add(" Canada");
    finalList = concat(x, y, z);
    System.out.println(finalList);
}

static ArrayList<String> concat(ArrayList<String>... lists) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (ArrayList<String> list : lists) {
        result = multiply(result, list);
    }
    return result;
}

static ArrayList<String> multiply(ArrayList<String> list1, ArrayList<String> list2) {
    if (list2.isEmpty()) { return list1; }
    if (list1.isEmpty()) { return list2; }

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String item2 : list2) {
        for (String item1 : list1) {
            result.add(item1 + item2);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Better to use a StringBuilder, but the idea is +1.

Comment: Sure, there is lot of optimization needed there.

Comment: sorry, that is the first list, in your case its `x`. all other lists should have atleast these many elements.

Comment: This won't provide all possible unordered combinations like the OP's example. You're getting the first element from each list, then the second, etc. Which as you alluded to, presumes equal length lists (which is not the same as the example), but more importantly doesn't cover all combinations, e.g. the first item from the first list and the second from the second.

Comment: yes, it doesnt provide combinations. it just does linear concats.

Comment: @kunal I just tested . You are right. It just works fine , if  have X and Y list have same number of elements, and fails if have different list sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
public class Lists {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<String>> finalList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

        List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
        x.add("Green");
        x.add("Red");
        x.add("Purple");

        List<String> y = new ArrayList<String>();
        y.add("Apple");

        List<String> z = new ArrayList<String>();
        z.add("USA");
        z.add("UK");
        z.add("France");

        finalList.add(x);
        finalList.add(y);
        finalList.add(z);

        for (String s: concat(finalList)) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    private static List<String> concat(List<List<String>> inputList) {
        if (inputList.size() == 1) {
            return inputList.get(0);
        } else {
            List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> prefixes = inputList.get(0);
            for (String prefix : prefixes) {
                for (String concat : concat(inputList.subList(1,inputList.size()))) {
                    newList.add(prefix + " " + concat);
                }
            }

            return newList;
        }
    }
}
```

gives:

```
Green Apple USA
Green Apple UK
Green Apple France
Red Apple USA
Red Apple UK
Red Apple France
Purple Apple USA
Purple Apple UK
Purple Apple France
```

Comment: This is a nice and clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple implementation:

```
List<ArrayList<String>> lists= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> final_list=new ArrayList<String>();;
            int i=0;
        while(true){
            StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

           for(ArrayList<String> currentList:lists){
            if(i<currentList.size()){
                temp.append(currentList.get(i));
            }
           }
           String row = temp.toString();
           if(row.length()==0){
               break;

           } else{
               final_list.add(row);
               i++;
           }
        }
```